# passing values between 2 threads without intrrrupting each other

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I am Creating 2 Classes with two different threads. And passing queue value from thread 1 to Thread 2, But i am not getting anything.

**Thread 1**

```
public class Thread1 implements Runnable {
    BlockingQueue queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    public void run() {
        for(int i=0; i<=10; i++) {
            try {
                queue.put(i+2);
                System.out.println("Thread 1");
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Thread1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Thread 2**

```
public class Thred2  implements Runnable {
    Thread1 Thread1 = new Thread1();
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0; i<=10; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Thread 2" + Thread1.queue.take());
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Thred2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Function**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Thred2());
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using two distinct Thread1 objects.

Comment: yes, i am creating Thread1 object

Comment: @benjamin What you mean by two distinct Thread1 objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are creating a *Thread1* object within the *main* method, and another *Thread1* object for the one instance of *Thred2*. These two *Thread1* objects are independent. In particular, each of the two objects has its own *LinkedBlockingQueue*.

You have to change your code in such a way, that *Thread1* and *Thred2* uses the same *LinkedBlockingQueue*. For example in the following way:

I am Creating 2 Classes with two different threads. And passing queue value from thread 1 to Thread 2, But i am not getting anything.

```
public class Thread1 implements Runnable {
    private final BlockingQueue queue;
    public Thread1(BlockingQueue queue) { this.queue = queue; }
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0; i<=10; i++) {
            try {
                queue.put(i+2);
                System.out.println("Thread 1");
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Thread1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Thred2  implements Runnable {
    private final BlockingQueue queue;
    public Thred2(BlockingQueue queue) { this.queue = queue; }
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0; i<=10; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Thread 2" + queue.take());
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Thred2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BlockingQueue queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Thread1(queue));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Thred2(queue));
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have another Question, what if another class method is called from thread 1 class and i have to transfer queue value of that third class to thread 2?